# ERROR: The request could not be satisfied CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, nodemailer

I am struggling to send emails to my server hosted on aws elastic beanstalk, using certificates from cloudfront, i am using nodemailer to send emails, it is working on my local environment but fails once deployed to AWS

**Email Code:**

```
const  transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'mail.email.co.za',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: 'example@email.co.za',
    pass: 'email@22'
  },
  secure:false,
  tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
  debug:true
});

const mailOptions = {
  from: 'example@email.co.za',
  to: email,
  subject: 'Password Reset OTP' ,
  text: `${OTP}`
}


try {
  const  response  = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions)

  return {error:false, message:'OTP successfully sent'   , response}
}catch(e) {

  return {error:false, message:'Problems sending OTP, Please try again'}
}
```

**Error from AWS:**

> The request could not be satisfied
>
> 504 ERROR  The request could not be satisfied CloudFront attempted to
>   establish a connection with the origin, but either the
>   attempt failed or the origin closed the connection.

**NB**: The code runs fine on my local

Comment: did you get the answer for this OR is there any resolution?